# Organising two column data

Tags: python, sorting, csv

Hi I have a two column data stored in a file called "Cv_0.out", each column is separated by two spaces

```
12  454
232  123
879  2354 
12312  23423
8794  1237
3245  34
```

I would like to then sort this data in ascending order based only on the right hand column values whilst at the same time keeping the pairs of values together, so reordering the left hand side values. I would like to get the following:

```
3245  34
232  123
12  454
8794  1237
879  2354
12312  23423
```

I have tried the following so far:

```
import sys,csv    
import operator
reader = csv.reader(open('Cv_0.out'),delimiter=' ')
sort = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[0]))
print sort
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Does it have to be Python? `sort -n Cv_0.out`

Comment: What exactly is not working in your current code? Could you please point out how the current output looks?

Answer (score 2):

Your input file can be dealt even without CSV:

```
with open("input") as f:
    lines = (map(int,x.strip().split()) for x in f)
    newLines = sorted(lines, key=lambda row: row[1])
    print "\n".join(str(x)+ " " + str(y)  for x,y in newLines)
```

IMO, the problem was using `row[0]` instead of `row[1]`, if you wanted to sort on the second column.